# How to disable all of document event of webrowser control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to fire touch manipulation of LayoutRoot that has a webbrowse control as a child. Any events of LayoutRoot are not fire bacause of webbrowse control..

So, is it possible to close all of event of webbrowser control on WPF?

Comment: What do you mean by 'close all of the events'?

Comment: I build a touch screen application and wanna use WebBrowser to display contents. I must control the touch event of my application, but when I use WebBrowser Control, it cannot see any Manipulate Event of WPF.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the WebBrowser control to respond to user for any of the user's actions, you can place a transparent panel on the Web Browser control and assign all the required event listeners of LayoutRoot to the panel.